# Why is this sum equal to this?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, summation, power-series

Given a matrix $A$ for which the norm of each eigenvalue is less than 1, I would like to know where the following equality comes from/why it is true:

$$
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} A^{Nl}=(I-A^N)^{-1}
$$

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| < 1$, we have $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty z^k = \frac{1}{1 - z}. $$
The formula you provided can be seen as a generalization of this formula.  To get some intuition for why it's true, consider the following:

\begin{align}
\left(\sum\limits_{l = 0}^\infty A^{N l} \right)(I - A^N)&= \sum\limits_{l = 0}^\infty (A^{N l} - A^{N (l + 1)}) \\
&=  \sum\limits_{l = 0}^\infty A^{N l} - \sum\limits_{l = 0}^\infty A^{N (l+1)} \\
&= \sum\limits_{l = 0}^\infty A^{N l} - \sum\limits_{l = 1}^\infty A^{N l} \\
&= A^0 \\
&= I
\end{align}
This would imply that  $\sum\limits_{l = 0}^\infty A^{N l} = (I - A)^{-1}$.  Note that the above calculation isn't exactly precise: we can't always manipulate these infinite series.  It turns out the assumption of all eigenvalues having norm $< 1$ gives convergence.  To see why this is the case, note that $\| A^{l N} \| \leq \|A \|^{l N} < 1$ for each $l, N$.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $S = I + {A^N} + {A^N}^2 + \ldots$

calculate $(I-A^N)S$ and use when $\|x\|<1$ , $\sum x^n $ converges converges & $\|A^N\|\leq\|A\|^N<1$.